# Ruby on Rails form_for as absolute url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, url

Hi i got 2 problems with submitting a form_for from a external source. Im using Jquery ajax for it. Its a form that is part of a widget, that gets added in when the user adds the code on there site (js)

This is the Haml code i'm using for it

```
    = form_for [@deck.user, @deck, @deck.recipients.new], html: { id: "emailform" }, remote: true do |f|
      = f.text_field :sender_name, placeholder: "Your name"
      = f.label :sender_name, "Your name", class: "name-label"

      = f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email of your friend"
      = f.label :email, "Email of your friend", class: "email-label"
      .email-send#submit
        = f.submit(type: "image", alt: "send email", src: image_url("widget/email.png"))
```

Problem 1:
It works without problems on the main site. 
But it should add the root url of our site to the path
how to do that?

Problem 2: 
When i manually add the root url and test it, it returns this error: 
Unknown format
which it probably caused by it trying to submit html instead of js format. how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= form_for @deck.user, url: something_url , id: "emailform", remote: true do |f|
    = f.text_field :sender_name, placeholder: "Your name"
    = f.label :sender_name, "Your name", class: "name-label"
    = f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email of your friend"
    = f.label :email, "Email of your friend", class: "email-label"
    .email-send#submit
        = f.submit(type: "image", alt: "send email", src: image_url("widget/email.png"))
```

`something_url` is the path you want to submit the form to. You most likely want to use a *named route* helper.

### added

Urls which are nested more than 2 levels tend to be really cumbersome and lead to a bunch of confusing dependency issues.

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
  resources :decks
end

resources :decks, only: [], shallow: true do
  resources :recipients
end
```

---

`$ rake routes`

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
        user_decks GET    /users/:user_id/decks(.:format)          decks#index
                   POST   /users/:user_id/decks(.:format)          decks#create
     new_user_deck GET    /users/:user_id/decks/new(.:format)      decks#new
         edit_deck GET    /decks/:id/edit(.:format)                decks#edit
              deck GET    /decks/:id(.:format)                     decks#show
                   PATCH  /decks/:id(.:format)                     decks#update
                   PUT    /decks/:id(.:format)                     decks#update
                   DELETE /decks/:id(.:format)                     decks#destroy
             users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
                   POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
         edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
              user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
                   PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                   PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                   DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
   deck_recipients GET    /decks/:deck_id/recipients(.:format)     recipients#index
                   POST   /decks/:deck_id/recipients(.:format)     recipients#create
new_deck_recipient GET    /decks/:deck_id/recipients/new(.:format) recipients#new
    edit_recipient GET    /recipients/:id/edit(.:format)           recipients#edit
         recipient GET    /recipients/:id(.:format)                recipients#show
                   PATCH  /recipients/:id(.:format)                recipients#update
                   PUT    /recipients/:id(.:format)                recipients#update
                   DELETE /recipients/:id(.:format)                recipients#destroy
```

This lets us post to `deck_recipients_url(deck_id: @deck)`

Comment: user_deck_recipients POST  /:user_id/:deck_id/recipients(.:format)                        recipients#create
this is the route that i want. how to get the root url before this one? url: user_deck_recipients_url does not work

Comment: Well first of all [nesting more than one layer down is not really recommended.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting). How to get the named route helper depends on how you  defined the route. If you add the relevant code from your routes file maybe I can help.

Comment: Also that is not a well formed RESTful url. it should be `/users/:user_id/decks/:deck_id/recipients`. Don't try to shorten urls by cheating REST. It will just come back in bite you in the bum.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
= form_for [@deck.user, @deck, @deck.recipients.new], html: { id: "emailform" }, remote: true, url: root_url_of_main_site , format: :js do |f|
```

root_url_of_main_site can easily be a string since apparently this form is rendered in another by another rails app

Comment: the other site does not has to have a rails app, its all loaded in on our rails app and loaded and appended to there site